# SQL Pivot issue shows sum in different lines.. SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have created below query, to check year wise qty issue for an item

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT  iid_item_code, sum(iid_issue_qty) as IssuedQty,    
YEAR(iid_created_date) as [ISYear], 
YEAR(iid_created_date) as [ISSyear],
LEFT(datename(Month,iid_created_date),3) as [ISSmonth]

From issue_inv_detail
where iid_item_code = '0101010001'
group by iid_item_code, iid_issue_qty, iid_created_date 
)as INVISS

PIVOT
(
    count(ISSyear)
    for [ISSmonth]IN (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
)as PVT
```

have resulted 3 different rows than expected one single line for year 2013

```
iid_item_code   IssuedQty   ISYear  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

0101010001  1   2013    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   0   3

0101010001  2   2013    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0101010001  5   2013    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

it was expected 8 qty in IssuedQty column and respective totals in months in single row

can somebody help me in this query please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `SUM(IssuedQty)` inside PIVOT instead of `count(ISSYear)`.
Also, [ISYear] is duplicated with [ISSyear]. You can remove one of them.

Using `SUM(IssuedQty)` should give you correct result.

Comment: Try adding the same calculation i.e. SUM(iid_issue_qty) as a new column after `sum(iid_issue_qty) as IssuedQty` so that IssuedQty can be used in PIVOT and the new column can give you the total.

Comment: not its not wokring by adding sum, it has generated line wise results of it.. so removed it..

i have another query also.. there are some months which is showing as NULL, can that be replaced with 0 (zero)?

Comment: i did in following way, still shows NULL in result

SELECT * from (
SELECT  a.iid_item_code, b.itm_itemdesc ,sum(isnull(a.iid_issue_qty,0)) as IssuedQty, 
YEAR(a.iid_created_date) as [ISYear], 
LEFT(datename(Month,a.iid_created_date),3) as [ISSmonth]
From issue_inv_detail a, Item_master b
where iid_item_code = 'GEC0122'
and YEAR(a.iid_created_date) >= '2012'
and a.iid_item_code = b.itm_itemcode
group by a.iid_item_code, a.iid_issue_qty, a.iid_created_date, b.itm_itemdesc
)as INVISS
PIVOT
(
 SUM(IssuedQty)
 for [ISSmonth] IN  (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
)as PVT

Comment: i m sorry i dont know how it works at sql fiddle, i have pasted results what i get from sql, your help is really appreciated.

iid_item_code ISYear Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
GEC0122 2012 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 84 86 217 185 502 168
GEC0122 2013 116 134 182 144 300 48 36 254 433 154 252 435
GEC0122 2014 186 60 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b1d5d/2

the out put i have managed to create at sql fiddle..

@abhishek chaudhary

Comment: I wanted to see the raw data. Using ISNULL in the subquery itself is working fine for me. I tries creating some sample data based on your table structure. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5df52/1

Answer (score 0):

Use only your item_code in your GROUP BY. Something like:

```
SELECT * from (
 SELECT  iid_item_code, sum(iid_issue_qty) as IssuedQty,
 YEAR(iid_created_date) as [ISYear], 
 YEAR(iid_created_date) as [ISSyear],
 LEFT(datename(Month,iid_created_date),3) as [ISSmonth]

From issue_inv_detail
where iid_item_code = '0101010001'
group by iid_item_code 
)as INVISS

PIVOT
(
count(ISSyear)
for [ISSmonth]IN (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
)as PVT
```

As your Created At date will be different for each record and hence it is showing 3 different records.

Comment: create date is the field for date..if i remove two other columns it results in error as 

Column 'issue_inv_detail.iid_created_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.